# How to get the files that were changed in a changeset in tfs

Tags: tfs

I was looking through a changeset in tfs and it has more than 6000 files in changeset but when  I check the files individually almost each file included in changeset was indentical to the previous version. Is there a way I can find what files were really changed through the changeset in tfs?

Answer (score 0):

this is an old one, see [this post](http://thesoftwarecondition.com/blog/2011/05/01/tfs-pending-changes-ignoring-files-which-are-identical-to-the-originals/). you have to be a little bit brave, so try it somewhere safe first.

specifically:

*Another option is to “Undo Checkout” all the changes, and clicking “No to All” when asked to confirm for undo checkout. This way Visual Studio will “undo checkout” all the files that are not changed, and all the changed files will remain checked out. I always use this method.*